# Compare Joining different fields

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have 2 files

```
file1.txt [syntax field1:filed2:field3:...]

123456:07102015174037:100 --> this should be matched
123457:03102015174037:354
123456:03102015174037:1
1234556:03102015174037:0    

file2.txt [syntax field3:filed4:field1:...]
100:03102015174037:123456 --> this should be matched
101:03145415174037:1234556
```

I wanted to check if 
From file1.txt combination of field1 & field2 exists in file2.txt at field3 & field1

At End I want to print only file1.txt content which are matched

so I ended up doing [To get only matched columns]

```
awk -F ':' '{print $1,$2}' file1.txt >> tmpfile1.txt
awk -F ':' '{print $1,$3}' file2.txt >> tmpfile2.txt

grep -f tmpfile1.txt tmpfile2.txt> match.txt
grep -f match.txt file1.txt >> file1updated.txt
cat fil1updated
 100:03102015174037:123456
```

Is there are one step & efficient way of doing this [Its like joins on columns in SQL]

Comment: Is this what you're looking for [gawk join two TSV by columns (a'la sql join)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23186/gawk-join-two-tsv-by-columns-ala-sql-join)?

Comment: @jayant, yes.. But just print all fields of file1.txt which is matched

Comment: Including a real sample of your files would be helpful. Are field3 or field1 unique?

Comment: @ghoti added 1 record match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this inline of course. But I prefer to create an awk script as such (`join.awk`)

```
NR==FNR {
  a[$1 FS $3] = $0; next
}

$3 FS $1 in a {print a[$3 FS $1]}
```

Then you can get your result by running

```
awk -F: -f join.awk file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks +1; accepted answer. What if we have more than 2 fields to match say $1,$2,$3

Comment: Then you would ask a new question. :-)